# Возможно ли использование стороннего ПО под GNU лицензией в коммерческих целях без изменения исходного кода этой программы?

Tags: лицензирование, gnu

Имею ли я право прикладывать к своему коммерческому проекту стороннее ПО с GNU лицензией не изменяя его код?

Comment: Просто прикладывать рядышком или таки связываться с ним?

Comment: @andreymal в одной папке лежит и запускается моей программой

Comment: [первоисточник информации по **разным** лицензиями gnu gpl](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.ru.html) ([неофициальные переводы нескольких лицензий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9))

Comment: @alexanderbarakin там воды много. хотелось бы ответ по существу

Comment: по первой ссылке вообще никакой «воды» (т.е., текстов лицензий, которых проектом gnu используется **много**). намекаю: вам для начала стоит определиться, о какой лицензии (и её версии) идёт речь.

Comment: следущие важные моменты, с которыми вам следует определиться, это: вы собираетесь что-либо распространять? в каком виде и под какими лицензиями? каким образом ваша программа взаимодействует с программами под другими лицензиями? // определение «коммерческий» можете из вопроса смело убрать: это не имеет отношения к вопросу и является лишь вашим сугубо личным делом — извлекать прибыль из вашей деятельности или не извлекать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin очень сложно определить это. я делаю это для заказчика и получу за это гонорар. а он скорее всего будет это распространять бесплатно. я это так вижу

Comment: @perfect, тогда не морочьте себе голову: пусть заказчик и разбирается со всеми этими вопросами. // вы в данной ситуации никак и ничем не ограничены.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну а как не морочить можно же пирацкий диск с виндовс дать человеку и не сказать об этом. а в случае появления у него проблем с законом проблемы автоматически появятся у меня.

Comment: «пирацкий диск с виндовс» не имеет отношения к вопросу. естественно, не надо ничего от заказчика скрывать: сообщите ему всё как есть. дальше пусть сам разбирается. надеюсь, в техзадании не было ничего оговорено про неиспользование сторонних программ?

Comment: имеет отношение. и в этом и в моем случае мы имеем отношения в рамках какой то лицензии. вот я и узнаю эти правила потому что это не бесполезная информация и всегда выручит и придаст уверенности. а вы меня сейчас отговариваете от этого. ладно подождем экспертного мнения если найдется таковой.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он требует уточнений. в частности, «лицензии gnu» не существует, как не существует «лицензии microsoft» и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin окей закрывайте. только вот тогда при установки очередного ПО не нажимайте кнопочку что вы согласны с условиями его использования ;)